# Product of two sequences that converge weakly

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology

I have two sequences $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ that converge weakly in $L^p$ and $L^q$,  ($1<p,q<\infty$) respectively to $f,g$ such that $(f_ng_n)$ converges weakly to
some $h$ in $L^r$ ($\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}$).
Notice that $f_n>0$ for all n.

I would like to know if $h-fg$ have a sign, for instance almost everywhere positive or negative. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_n(x) = g_n(x) = \sin(nx)1_{[0,\pi]}(x)$ for all real number $x$. Then $f_n = g_n \to 0$ weakly in $L^2$, but $f_ng_n \to 1/2$ weakly in $L^1$. Multiplying $g_n$ by a fixed bounded measurable function $b$, you can get whatever you want for the sign of the weak limit of $f_ng_n$, which is $(1/2)b$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The sequences converge **weakly**, and I think that we do not have a priori a subsequence which converges almost everywhere. Unless I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the word weakly. So it is less simple.

Comment: I know that if, $g_n=P(f_n)$ where $P$ is a non decreasing function of $f_n$, then the positivity of $h-fg$ holds. Since for all test function $\varphi$ and for all $n$, $\int (P(f_n)-P(f))(f_n-f)\varphi\geqslant 0$

Comment: @user1107692 I corrected my answer according to your assumptions. Everything can happen.

Comment: You're right. Thanks!

Comment: For your counterexample all the assumptions are not satisfied, for example positivity, but it taught me to see that what I was looking for was impossible.